# Using Selected is not displaying anything in dropdownlist

Tags: php, mysql, sql

### I'm displayed a dropdown list of initials that come from a table. I insert "--" at the start before getting the initials from the table.
It goes:

AB
CD
EF

I want it to select the default. $init is the defaulkt

The code below works for '--' but not for the initials.
On  the While, if I remove the if statement and just leave the 'else'
echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['init'] . " ";
it is OK.
The first half of the if statement should be the same but with 'selected added.
I don't understand why it is not working.

All I get is "--", not the initials, or any other following input.

Thanks for your help.

```
<?php
echo $init;
// Drop down list initials
    $conn=createconnection();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE lef='0' AND man='1' ORDER BY init";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "Updated by and date<br>";
        echo "<select name='select_initial' id='select_initial'>";
        if ($init==="--"){
            echo "<option value='" . '0' . "'selected>" .'--' . " </option>";
        } else {
            echo "<option value='" . '0' . "'>" . '--' . " </option>";  
        }
                
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if ($init===$row('init')) {
                echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'selected>" . $row['init'] . " </option>";
            } else {
                echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['init'] . " </option>";   
            }
        }
        echo "</select>";
        //echo "<br><br>";
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: Put a space between `'` and `selected` like `echo "<option value='" . '0' . "' selected>" .'--' . " </option>";

Comment: Of course the official doc states you should use `selected="selected"` but almost all browser accept/understand just `selected`

Answer (score 0):

I found if I used square brackets round the $row function it worked:
if ($init===$row['init']) {